# What statistical test? DV: Categorical IV: Continuous

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, spss, continuous-data

This is for a university essay.

The data that I would like to compare are General Self Rated Attractiveness (GSA) and Sexual Orientation Index (SOI). There are 203 individuals with each with an SOI value and a GSA value.

GSA data is on a scale from 1 - 7

SOI is a measure of interest in casual  sex. The higher the score, the more likely a participant is to have  engage and continue to engage in casual sex. The numbers on the SOI are completely arbitrary. They range from -33.01 to 18.38.

My first inclination was to categorise the SOI data into something similar to GSA, however I'm not sure if this is the right path to go down.

My next port of call was to do an LDA or QDA, however I have no idea what any of the outputs on SPSS mean, or how to interpret them/ put them into descriptives in my essay.

Comment: How about a scatterplot and a correlation? I don't see a reason to rescale SOI.